# Get only the oldest entry in a join

Tags: mysql, join

So I have a table `bugs`

|bugid| title|

the table is lacking a date column. But when creating a new entry, most likely always a new entry gets created in `bugnotes` as well saying "bug created" with the date.

`bugnotes`:

| bugnotesid | bugid | datetime | text |

I want to list all bugs, showing the date of the oldest entry in `bugnotes` if available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query below. Note it only lists the bug and its derived creation date (i.e.: doesn't include the bugnotes, etc). An `OUTER` join was preferred to return all bugs, regardless of whether or not they have any associated bugnotes.

```
SELECT bugid
     , bugtitle
     , MIN(notetime) created
  FROM bugs b
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bugnotes USING (bugid)
 GROUP BY bugid, bugtitle;
```

But a more solid solution would be to add a column to your `bugs` table to automatically capture the creation time.  Note: you'll have to backfill any existing bug records with a value for this column -- which you could obtain from the `SELECT` query above.

```
ALTER TABLE bugs ADD created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

**EDIT:** Here's the "backfill" `UPDATE` statement, assuming you've already added the `created` column:

```
UPDATE bugs b
SET created = (SELECT MIN(notetime)
               FROM bugnotes
               WHERE bugid=b.bugid);
```

**EDIT2:** I just profiled the two queries on MySQL 5.6.13 Community. This looks a little more sane, since both queries have in their profile things like `checking permissions`; shouldn't any SELECT query always have to check permissions (except maybe when running `skip-grant-tables` mode)?  I'm baffled why the previous profiling didn't show permission checks on the one short profile.

Anyhow, I don't think the Durations are significant.  I ran Verace's query first and it took a good amount of time in `starting` and `opening tables`.  I ran my own query second and those same items took less time.  I'm 99.9% sure that I would see the reverse if I had simply chosen a different order.  Therefore, I'm treating the durations as junk.

The first query run will typically take the work of loading caches.  Flushing MySQL's caches alone is not good enough.  Your OS might be caching disk blocks.  Even if you tried to flush the OS cache, your hard disk itself probably has at least an 8MB cache.  I suppose if you wanted to level the field with two queries, you could run them alternately 5 times to stabilize any effects of software and hardware caching.

Or another plan (and this is probably overkill): reboot the server, run query A and view its profile.  Reboot again and run & profile only query B.  Compare the two profiles.

My conclusion is that doing MySQL profiling on small tables (e.g. 10 rows) is fruitless.  Side note, `SHOW PROFILE` is deprecated in MySQL 5.6.7+, in favor of using the `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` objects instead.

```
mysql> show profile for query 1; -- Verace
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.055357 |
| checking permissions | 0.000019 |
| checking permissions | 0.000004 |
| checking permissions | 0.000013 |
| Opening tables       | 0.017346 |
| init                 | 0.000045 |
| System lock          | 0.000015 |
| optimizing           | 0.000005 |
| optimizing           | 0.000008 |
| statistics           | 0.000037 |
| preparing            | 0.000020 |
| Creating tmp table   | 0.000047 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000038 |
| statistics           | 0.000089 |
| preparing            | 0.000039 |
| executing            | 0.016013 |
| Sending data         | 0.000179 |
| executing            | 0.000007 |
| Sending data         | 0.004832 |
| Creating sort index  | 0.000062 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000017 |
| Creating sort index  | 0.000062 |
| end                  | 0.000007 |
| query end            | 0.000023 |
| closing tables       | 0.000005 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000016 |
| closing tables       | 0.000019 |
| freeing items        | 0.000041 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000028 |
+----------------------+----------+
29 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

.

```
mysql> show profile for query 2; -- Josh
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000116 |
| checking permissions | 0.000008 |
| checking permissions | 0.000015 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000045 |
| init                 | 0.000060 |
| System lock          | 0.000021 |
| optimizing           | 0.000010 |
| statistics           | 0.000034 |
| preparing            | 0.000033 |
| Creating tmp table   | 0.000060 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000006 |
| executing            | 0.000011 |
| Sending data         | 0.000168 |
| Creating sort index  | 0.000046 |
| end                  | 0.000006 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000016 |
| end                  | 0.000007 |
| query end            | 0.000010 |
| closing tables       | 0.000017 |
| freeing items        | 0.000046 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000041 |
+----------------------+----------+
21 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT3:** Sample output. I correctly get one row per bugid. This is using the sample data that Verace cooked up. If the query is not working the same for you, I suspect we have different source data.  You could clear this up by posting a SQL Fiddle with a small amount of representative data, or perhaps simply edit your question and add some sample data to it.

```
mysql> SELECT bugid
    ->      , bugtitle
    ->      , MIN(notetime) created
    ->   FROM bugs b
    ->   LEFT OUTER JOIN bugnotes USING (bugid)
    ->  GROUP BY bugid, bugtitle;
+-------+----------------+---------------------+
| bugid | bugtitle       | created             |
+-------+----------------+---------------------+
|     1 | the first bug  | 2014-03-14 00:00:00 |
|     2 | the second bug | 2014-02-14 00:00:00 |
|     3 | the third bug  | 2013-03-14 00:00:00 |
+-------+----------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: And for your bonus, would you be able to give the update? It's defeating me - long day!

Comment: @Vérace, the update is deceptively simple.  See EDIT above.

Comment: Deceptive being the word  :-) <kicking myself...>

Comment: Joshua - could you possibly take a look at my edit to my own answer? I'm puzzled by the profiling results?

Comment: @Vérace, I'm puzzled by your profiling results, too. See my new EDIT2 in my answer

Comment: this only returns me one row, can that be? I actually wanted all bug rows, but without dublicates

Comment: @Toskan, see my EDIT3 above. I thought you wanted to see one record per bugid, showing the earliest notetime if available.  Is this not what you were asking for?

Comment: @JoshuaHuber :That was my take also Joshua. The English was fairly unambiguous "showing the date of the oldest entry in bugnotes if available" - your OUTER join giving any NULLs was a nice touch. Re. the profiling - your point about it being deprecated is well made - I do want to learn the P_S though - if my weekend isn't too hectic, I might go through that approach to profiling the queries - it'll be a learning experience if nothing else.

Comment: @Verace and josh: yes that was what I wanted, somehow I got overall only 1 record. E.g. only one bug in total. I guess that was my bad since the sql is more complicated in the actual application. I'll accept this answer here because of the update statement, that I actually ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want something like this (see below for table defs). Something appears to have happened my SQLFiddle demo.

```
SELECT bs.bugid, bs.bugtitle, bn.bugnotesid, bn.notetime, bn.notetext 
FROM bugs bs, bugnotes bn
JOIN  
(
  SELECT bugnotesid, MIN(notetime) 
  FROM bugnotes 
  GROUP By (bugid)
) mytab
ON bn.bugnotesid = mytab.bugnotesid 
WHERE bs.bugid = bn.bugid;

CREATE TABLE bugs values
(
  bugid int,
  bugtitle varchar(34)
);

INSERT INTO bugs values(1, 'the first bug');
INSERT INTO bugs values(2, 'the second bug');
INSERT INTO bugs values(3, 'the third bug');

CREATE TABLE bugnotes
(
  bugnotesid int,
  bugid int,
  notetime datetime,
  notetext varchar(400)
);

INSERT INTO bugnotes values(1, 1, '2014-03-14', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(2, 1, '2014-03-15', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(3, 1, '2014-03-16', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(4, 1, '2014-03-17', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(5, 2, '2014-02-14', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(6, 2, '2014-02-20', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(7, 2, '2014-02-22', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(8, 2, '2014-02-25', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(9, 2, '2014-02-28', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(10, 3, '2013-03-14', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(11, 3, '2013-03-16', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(12, 3, '2013-03-19', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(13, 3, '2013-03-20', 'afasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO bugnotes values(14, 3, '2013-03-27', 'afasdfasdf');
```

[EDIT - after profiling the two queries offered as solutions here]

This bit is really a question to Joshua - not sure if I should make it a new post or keep going here - I can always move it if requested.

Hi Joshua,

I'm sort of starting with MySQL so I took advantage of our exchange to profile our two responses to the OP. I'm a bit puzzled by what I found. Mine takes ~ 200 us, whereas yours appears to take more than double that - and there are far more rows in yours (more info?). I'm curious as to why? Do you know what's going on.

I hasten to add that I did a RESET QUERY CACHE before running the second (mine) query. I also ran them in reverse order and obtained the same result.

I'm baffled!

Joshua's query.

```
mysql> show profile for query 1;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000186 |
| checking permissions | 0.000011 |
| checking permissions | 0.000010 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000043 |
| init                 | 0.000069 |
| System lock          | 0.000019 |
| optimizing           | 0.000012 |
| statistics           | 0.000038 |
| preparing            | 0.000057 |
| Creating tmp table   | 0.000056 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000008 |
| executing            | 0.000006 |
| Sending data         | 0.000218 |
| Creating sort index  | 0.000060 |
| end                  | 0.000011 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000029 |
| end                  | 0.000009 |
| query end            | 0.000013 |
| closing tables       | 0.000018 |
| freeing items        | 0.000027 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000024 |
+----------------------+----------+
21 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> reset query cache;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

My query.

```
mysql> show profile for query 2;
+----------------+----------+
| Status         | Duration |
+----------------+----------+
| starting       | 0.000131 |
| query end      | 0.000010 |
| closing tables | 0.000007 |
| freeing items  | 0.000020 |
| cleaning up    | 0.000031 |
+----------------+----------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This helped me. Not sure why but SQL Fiddle really doesn't like this particular schema.

Comment: I think it's giving problems at the minute. I can't seem to load this simple schema. Nice SQL BTW.

Comment: I get this error: "Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity"

Comment: Mine just hangs on "Building Schema".